# PHP without a server

Tags: php, embed, command-line-interface

I have a C# application that needs to call a PHP script, and get the output, in the fastest possible way. The options I explored:

- Executing the script with PHP CLI (Pro: Easy / Cons: No Opcode Cache / Precompilation ]
- Compiling the PHP (Phalanger, Hiphop, etc.) [Pro: No Webserver / Con: Compatibility ]
- Using an embedded webserver (AppWeb, Cherokee, Lighttpd) [Pro: Simple / Cons: Deployment ]

Are there any other options left?

EDIT: The best possible option would be to make use of the build-in FastCGI server of PHP, by running `php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1`. But there seems no (C#) code to talk to a server available. While there are so many server-side libraries (like FCGIDotNet and SharpCGI), they all implement the server-side of the protocol.

Comment: What does the script do?

Comment: Any requirements discussion must involve, first and foremost, _what the solution must do_. Yet, here, you don't even mention it.

Comment: @Fase: ... which is a packaged webserver. Relevance?

Comment: Why is executing PHP in the CLI very slow? And why can't C# just do the job?

Comment: if you can port the script into C#, why not?

Comment: On what do you base the Con for using PHP CLI?  It's quite fast and obviously faster than using a webserver which is basically just adding overhead on top of the PHP interpreter.

Comment: If you want the fastest way - yes, convert bytecode to c++ and compile it, problem solved. But I agree with Tomalak.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper Executing PHP on a file containing `<?php ?>` via CLI here is essentially instantaneous.

Comment: PHP compile/startup overhead would only be relevant if the PHP script would be executed literally hundreds or thousands or millions of times by the parent C# program. If it's a one-time-per-c#-execution, the overhead will be essentially zero.

Comment: @Kevin: It is an existing PHP library, I dont want to re-write it from scratch in C#

Comment: @Joshua: Then rewrite it once in C/C++, make the dll/so from it, and use it everywhere you could imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other option could be to run the PHP CLI script as a daemon (good blog post on this [here](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/)).

If the script has a particularly long startup/cleanup, then running it as a daemon would mean that you only do this once.

The downside is that you'd need to write a way of communicating with that daemon, to get the data from C# to it.  You'd also need to keep an eye out on its memory usage over time.

The best method is always going to be specific to your script though.

Comment: Looks very interesting! The problem is that CLI is the slowest on Windows, and the script is for Linux. Since my app is crossplatform, I still need a Windows-solution, but very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, PHP originally stood for "*Personal Home Page*", it is now said to stand for "*PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor*", which literally states it's usage, and basically is not something that a developer would embed into his application just to have a scripting option.

Unless you have some really specific piece of software and strong arguments, I'd suggest you to stick to [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), or similar scripting libraries which are easy to embed and maintain. Otherwise, use it the way as everyone is using it, CLI. Or else be prepared to face the consequences.

Comment: Im trying to re-use an existing library, so I have no choice for other languages, except for rewriting the whole library from scratch.